# ¿Cómo Generar Códigos de Barra de un Producto específico en Ireport dependiendo de la Cantidad de Stock?

Tags: java, java-swing, ireport

Estoy intentando generar Código de Barra para un Producto específico cuya cantidad en Stock se encuentra guardada en la Base de Datos.

Lo que necesito es que dependiendo de esa cantidad de Stock se generen la misma cantidad de códigos de barra en el reporte; de manera a que pueda imprimirse dicho reporte y pegar por cada producto existente en el depósito

Agradecería la ayuda que puedan brindar!

Answer (score 2):

Realiza una consulta que te devuelva tantas filas como stock tengas y añade el codigo de barras en la banda "detail". Ésta se repite por cada fila que exista.

Para crear N filas por cantidad de stock puedes hacer algo así en Oracle:

```
SELECT 'registro' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT TABLA_STOCK.CANTIDADSTOCK FROM TABLA_STOCK WHERE TABLA_STOCK.IDPRODUCTO= 'XXX');
```

Si usas otra base de datos, puede que exista su equivalente.

Comment: Algún ejemplo de dicho tipo de consulta?

Comment: Si utilizas Oracle, puedes utilizar la consulta que te comento.